# Failed to retrieve data (SQL Server Authentication)

Tags: sql-server, wpf, visual-studio, datasource

I am trying to connect to a database created in the SQL Server 2016 express edition, through Data Source Configuration Wizard in VS2017 Express edition, with SQL Server Authentication.
I created the user in SQL Server, and when I test the connection works perfectly, but vs displays the error. Also in Server properties, I set up SQL and Windows authentication.

[image: Server properties]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I checked the checkbox remember password while creating connection string...and now can retrieve data for that user. In connection string is added persisted security=true. Still don't know why this need to be checked, because I follow example without persisted security, and there it worked, but on my PC didn't.